# How do I process files with matching pattern in nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

Suppose I have nextflow channels:

```
Channel.fromFilePairs( "test/read*_R{1,2}.fa" )
       .set{ reads }
reads.view() 

Channel.fromPath(['test/lib_R1.fa','test/lib_R2.fa'] )
        .set{ libs }
libs.view()
```

Which results in:

```
// reads channel
[read_b, [<path>/test/read_b_R1.fa, <path>/test/read_b_R2.fa]]
[read_a, [<path>/test/read_a_R1.fa, <path>/test/read_a_R2.fa]]

// libs channel
<path>/test/lib_R1.fa
<path>/test/lib_R2.fa
```

How do I run a process `foo` that executes matching read-lib pair, where the same lib is used for all read pairs? So basically I want to execute `foo` 4 times:

```
foo(test/read_b_R1.fa, test/lib_R1.fa)
foo(test/read_b_R2.fa, test/lib_R2.fa)
foo(test/read_a_R1.fa, test/lib_R1.fa)
foo(test/read_a_R2.fa, test/lib_R2.fa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same library for all read pairs, what you really want is a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) which can be read an unlimited number of times without being consumed. Note that a value channel is implicitly created by a process when it's invoked with a simple value. This *could* indeed be a list of files, but it looks like what you want is just one of these to correspond to each of the R1 or R2 reads. I think the simplest solution here is to just include your process using an [alias](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-aliases) so that you can pass in the required channels/files without too much effort:

```
params.reads = 'test/read*_R{1,2}.fa'

include { foo as foo_r1 } from './modules/foo.nf'
include { foo as foo_r2 } from './modules/foo.nf'


workflow {

    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( params.reads )
        .multiMap { sample, reads ->
            def (r1, r2) = reads

            read1:
                tuple(sample, r1)
            read2:
                tuple(sample, r2)
        }
        .set { reads }

    lib_r1 = file('test/lib_R1.fa')
    lib_r2 = file('test/lib_R2.fa')

    foo_r1(reads.read1, lib_r1)
    foo_r2(reads.read2, lib_r2)
}
```

Contents of `./modules/foo.nf`:

```
process foo {

    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(fasta)
    path(lib)

    """
    echo $sample, $fasta, $lib
    """
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [confident_boyd] DSL2 - revision: 8c81e2d743
executor >  local (6)
[a8/e8a752] process > foo_r1 (2) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[75/2b32f5] process > foo_r2 (3) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
readC, readC_R2.fa, lib_R2.fa

readA, readA_R1.fa, lib_R1.fa

readC, readC_R1.fa, lib_R1.fa

readB, readB_R2.fa, lib_R2.fa

readA, readA_R2.fa, lib_R2.fa

readB, readB_R1.fa, lib_R1.fa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
process FOO {
  debug true
  input:
    tuple val(files), path(lib)
  output:
    stdout
  script:
  file_a = files[0]
  file_b = files[1]
  """
  echo $file_a with $lib
  echo $file_b with $lib
  """
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .of(['read_b', [file('/test/read_b_R1.fa'), file('/test/read_b_R2.fa')]],
        ['read_a', [file('/test/read_a_R1.fa'), file('/test/read_a_R2.fa')]]
    )
    .set { reads }
  Channel
    .of(file('/test/lib_R1.fa'),
        file('/test/lib_R2.fa')
    )
    .set { libs }

  reads
    .map { sample, files -> files }
    .flatten()
    .map { file -> [file.name.split('_')[2].split('.fa')[0], file]}
    .groupTuple()
    .set { reads }
  libs
    .map { file -> [file.name.split('_')[1].split('.fa')[0], file]}
    .set { libs }
  reads
    .join(libs)
    .map { Rx, path, lib -> [path, lib] }
    | FOO
}
```

The output of the script above is:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.4
Launching `ex.nf` [elegant_wiles] DSL2 - revision: 00862286fd
executor >  local (2)
[58/9b3cf1] process > FOO (2) [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
/test/read_b_R1.fa with lib_R1.fa
/test/read_a_R1.fa with lib_R1.fa

/test/read_b_R2.fa with lib_R2.fa
/test/read_a_R2.fa with lib_R2.fa
```

EDIT as a reply to the comment below.
If you want the process to run once per element in the channel, check the modified version below:

```
process FOO {
  debug true
  input:
    tuple val(file), path(lib)
  output:
    stdout
  script:
  """
  echo $file with $lib
  """
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .of(['read_b', [file('/test/read_b_R1.fa'), file('/test/read_b_R2.fa')]],
        ['read_a', [file('/test/read_a_R1.fa'), file('/test/read_a_R2.fa')]]
    )
    .set { reads }
  Channel
    .of(file('/test/lib_R1.fa'),
        file('/test/lib_R2.fa')
    )
    .set { libs }

  reads
    .map { sample, files -> files }
    .flatten()
    .map { file -> [file.name.split('_')[2].split('.fa')[0], file]}
    .groupTuple()
    .set { reads }
  libs
    .map { file -> [file.name.split('_')[1].split('.fa')[0], file]}
    .set { libs }
  reads
    .join(libs)
    .map { Rx, path, lib -> [path, lib] }
    .map { x, y -> [[x[0], y], [x[1], y]] }
    .flatMap()
    | FOO
}
```

Output:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.4
Launching `ex.nf` [sharp_ekeblad] DSL2 - revision: 1412af632e
executor >  local (4)
[a0/416f59] process > FOO (1) [100%] 4 of 4 ✔
/test/read_b_R2.fa with lib_R2.fa

/test/read_a_R2.fa with lib_R2.fa

/test/read_a_R1.fa with lib_R1.fa

/test/read_b_R1.fa with lib_R1.fa
```

Comment: so this seems to call foo twice, once for R1 and once for R2. How do I make it to call foo 4 times instead? e.g. I want to have separate calls for foo(read_a_R1.fa, lib_R1.fa) and foo(read_b_R1.fa, lib_R1.fa)

Comment: just found out, seems like I can use transpose after joining

Comment: It calls `foo` twice because there are two elements in the channel you provided. If your channel had 4 elements (4 files, instead of those 2 tuples), `foo` would have been called 4 times. You can use operators to split the channel differently if you want one task per file.